# How to multilingual url when user enter, copy paste or click url from other website

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have angularjs project implemented multi-language and using ui-router for routing. Every language will be have different url. Ex:

- http://example.com/!#/en-us/english-title
- http://example.com/!#/es-es/spanish-title

All state with url registered automatically when app run and load them from database. Ex:

```
angular.module('bxApp').run(["$http", function ($http) {
  $http.get('/Home/Routes').success(function (result) {
    result = result || {};
    if (angular.isDefined(result) && result !== null) {
      _.each(result.Routes, function (route) {
        stateProvider.state(route.Name, {
          url: route.Url,
          templateUrl: route.TemplateUrl,
          controller: route.Controller,
        });
      });
    }
  });
}]);
```

It work well but it will not work when user copy this link and paste to browser or click this link from other website . I think because of state can't found so it will be redirect to default and it does not keep url that user enter or copy.
In this case , How to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your states as a result of an HTTP call to your server: the problem is that these states are defined too late for the user to navigate to them when he pastes the URL in a new tab.

To understand, let's deconstruct what happens :

1. The user is on the initial page / other website, and copies the URL.
2. He pastes it in a new tab
3. Your angular application loads, finishes its config phase without having declared any of those states, and sends an HTTP call.
4. ui-router fails to route to a state matching the pasted URL, since the corresponding state is not here yet, and redirects to default
5. The HTTP response comes back, and your states are created (but too late).

**How to make it work ?**

My first reaction would simply *not* to store your states on your server. Unless you want the very core of your UX to be language-dependent, you don't have to do that.

But hey, let's say we want to do it anyway. I suggest you try this : declare a toplevel `'language'` state, and have it load the other states in a `resolve` clause. This will 'block' the routing until the other states are declared :

```
angular.module('bxApp')
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .state('language',{
        url: '/:language',
        resolve: {
          childrenLoaded: ['$http', function ($http) {
            // returning a promise is essential to have the 'waiting' behavior
            return $http.get('/Home/Routes').then(function (data) {
              var result = data.result || {};
              if (angular.isDefined(result) && result !== null) {
                _.each(result.Routes, function (route) {
                  $stateProvider.state(route.Name, {
                    url: route.Url,
                    templateUrl: route.TemplateUrl,
                    controller: route.Controller
                  });
                });
              }
            });
          }]
        }
      })
  }]);
```

Again, this approach is probably asking for trouble : I strongly recommend you hardcode your states instead of storing them in a database. If all that varies from one language to another is the text and URL, then you will be *fine* with an URL param.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But , Can I implement this requirement? Or other solution?

Comment: I will hardcode states on client.But, I have a question : How to detect language to can register exactly state with that language?